# Hiding a button on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to hide a button on click using Bootstrap/JavaScript. Here is my button code:

```
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="menu-toggle" onclick="hideBtn();">I understand</a>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hidebtn(){
        document.getElementById('menu-toggle').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

It isn't working, any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Typo? `hideBtn` & `hidebtn` ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k44qrydw/

Comment: Thats it, thank you! What a wally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function hideBtn()
    {
    document.getElementById('menu-toggle').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```html
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="menu-toggle" onclick="hideBtn();">I understand</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with jQuery:

```
function hide(){
    $( "#button" ).addClass( "hide" );
}
```

HTML & CSS:

```
<a id="#button" onClick="hide()">Button</a>

#button.hide {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, had a typo in my function call.