# how to hide button when i click the button to show content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to hide button when i click it. But i want my content to be shown when i click the button.

```
#sectiontohide{
display: none;}

function toggle_div_fun(id) {

   var divelement = document.getElementById(id);

   if(divelement.style.display == 'none')
      divelement.style.display = 'block';
   else
      divelement.style.display = 'none';
}

<button onclick="toggle_div_fun('sectiontohide');">Display Content</button>
<div id="sectiontohide">`
```

`this is the content i'd like to show when i click the button and button should disappear`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding a button on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373038/hiding-a-button-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function toggle_div_fun(id, btn) {
   var divelement = document.getElementById(id);
   btn.style.display = "none";
   if(divelement.style.display == 'none')
      divelement.style.display = 'block';
   else
      divelement.style.display = 'none';
}

<button onclick="toggle_div_fun('sectiontohide', this);">Display Content</button>
<div id="sectiontohide" style="display:none">Content</div>
```

If you do not need to reuse the code, maybe this is simpler:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('sectiontohide').style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">Display Content</button>
<div id="sectiontohide" style="display:none">Content</div>
```